What does "spare capacity available: 99%" mean in a disk report?
Screenshot taken in HWiNFO:

What does "spare capacity available: 99%" mean in a disk report?

Thanks, I am not asking about how reliable the remaining lifetime of an SSD is. I am not asking about the meaning of "spare capacity available: 99%".

A storage drive will set aside X% of its actual total capacity, and only advertise 100%-X of actual capacity as available. These blocks become the "spare sectors" that are used to "replace" "bad" sectors as those are discovered during the life of the drive.

@sawdust thanks, got it, can you please post as an answer?

@FranckDernoncourt - You might want to read the answers that question received as it talks about the spare capacity of an SSD and what the attribute your asking about indicates

@sawdust not just to replace bad sectors, but for SSD's they are used so TRIM can work much more effectively, and a drive does not slow down to a crawl when its nearly filled up.

A storage drive will set aside X% of its actual total capacity, and only advertise 100%-X of actual capacity as available. These blocks become the "spare sectors" that are used to "replace" "bad" sectors as those are discovered during the life of the drive.
Both HDD and SSD set aside such spare blocks to relieve the host OS of bad block maintenance.

What does "spare capacity available: 99%" mean in a disk report?

Of the total number of spare sectors that have been set aside, only 1% has been used.
On the good side, that means that there are still many spare sectors available if/when bad blocks are encountered.
On the bad side, it may mean that one or more bad blacks have been discovered (and replaced), and hopefully this is not the start of a trend.
